# Have ROW_NUMBER (or like function) reset after a certain number of rows are counted

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking for a way to have the row_number() function reset to 1 after counting X amount of rows.

I'd like my data to look like this.

For example, I'd want to reset after 3 rows

```
YEAR    RowNumber
-----------------
2000    1
2001    2
2002    3
2003    1
2004    2
2005    3
2006    1
2007    2
2008    3
2009    1
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You can `PARTITION OVER` some column or function.  That way you can have your row number reset however you want.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Right. I want this to be run against random data so there isn't going to be a constant. The Year field was just an example. I want it to change no matter what the data is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer is close, but needs a `CASE` to account for Rownumber 3

```
select 
    RowNumber = case when row_number() over (order by a) % 3 = 0 then 3 else row_number() over (order by a) % 3 end
    ,a
from (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8)) as V(a)
```

So in your case

```
RowNumber = case when row_number() over (order by Year) % 3 = 0 then 3 else row_number() over (order by Year) % 3 end
```

Or, using `REPLACE`

```
RowNumber = replace(row_number() over (order by Year) % 3,0,3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an expression like this:

```
(ROWNUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY YEAR)) % 3
```

Basically taking the remainder after division by 3

Comment: Ahhh....yes. This is close to what I'm looking for. Is there any way to prevent it from returning zero when it resets?

Comment: add case when 0 then 3